# copy cron job from one domain to another on same server

Tags: linux, centos, bash, cron

I have just set up the `.com` of a domain that previous ran on `.co.uk` on the same server, I have copied all the files, ran through them using bash to change the domain anywhere it was referenced, same for DB, and all went great, same with the redirect. But now I want to move the cron jobs across using bash.

I was thinking

```
sudo cat /var/spool/cron/sbadmin | while read -r line; do echo $line;done > /var/spool/cron/sbcomadmin
```

But permission is denied on the new file. How can permission be denied when I am in sudo mode?

The domain will need changing in the new cron file aswell but I was thinking I could use sed on that, either during the copy or after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the loop you are using is useless. You command can be written as:

```
$ sudo cat /var/spool/cron/sbadmin > /var/spool/cron/sbcomadmin
```

This will not work. You need to use the following command instead to create the file as root:

```
$ cat /var/spool/cron/sbadmin | sudo tee /var/spool/cron/sbcomadmin
```

The `tee` will write the output to both stdout and the provided file. If you don't want to write to stdout, you can append `> /dev/null` at the end of the previous command. Also, you can use `tee -a` to work in append mode if needed to replace `>>`.

Comment: Great thanks. I just added to my question, I need to change the domains in the cron file from mydomain.co.uk to mydomain.com, I was thinking maybe use sed, is there anyway I can incorporate this into the same command.

Comment: @LiamBailey: Yes, you can use `sed` in the command. So it comes `cat file | sed 's/co.uk/com/' | sudo tee file`.

Comment: so, just to confirm if I didn't want the output the command would be `cat /var/spool/cron/sbadmin > /dev/null | sudo tee /var/spool/cron/sbcomadmin or would the > /dev/null go after the filename on sudo tee?

Comment: @LiamBailey: The 2nd one.

Answer (score 0):

Assumming the userids and group information are the same.....have you thought of using cpio or tar...make the archive....send it to the other system.....restore it....make the minor edits....done.  A shell loop like this is not a very efficient method especially if there are a large number of files.